# How Pylint determine Instance has variable or not

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pylint

I have written simple file and run Pylint on this code code. Does anyone have idea **How Pylint determine that Class sample does not have second variable.**

> Purpose: I would like to write simple script which will read sample
>   file(python code) and check which instance variable is accessed and
>   set by Instance. Ex if I write in main time.initial_time than my script able to detect that initial_time has been accessed by time Instance. it will be run at the run time. I mean, it will be part of existing flow
>
> **Real Purpose**
>   To filter out unused member variable of class which is used thousands places and more than 100 variable

Sample file

```
"""testing pylint code"""
#!/usr/bin/env py
class Sample(object):
    """create sample class"""
    def __init__(self):
        """seting variable"""
        self.intial_time = 0

def main():
    """main functionality"""
    time = Sample()
    print time.second

if __name__ == " __main__":
    main()
```

Pylint Error:

```
************* Module class_instance
R:  3, 0: Too few public methods (0/2) (too-few-public-methods)
E: 12,10: Instance of 'Sample' has no 'second' member (no-member)
```

Comment: FYI, the actual source code of the rule: https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/5d0e45d47758ed133e176a4b9a99f256ea9e3584/pylint/checkers/typecheck.py#L338.

Comment: Thx for pointing this code...